# Rendering two React components in a sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**In Summary: {
How can I merge those 2 arrays into one. As in, instead of having it like this:
[1st,new1st,...] [2nd,new2nd,...]
I want it to be like this:
[1st,2nd,new1st,new2nd,...]
}**

I have this note app that I am creating. I am trying to render the two components so that each note rendered is kind of the last element of an array. So, in short, I want each component to be below the previous added note (think of it like a list where each added input is added after the previous list items).

So, this is how it looks before adding anything.

[image]

and this is how it looks after adding one note on each create area.
[image]

and this is what I am trying to avoid after adding the new notes from each note create area.
[image]

What I want is

**-1st -2nd -new1st - new2nd**

As in no matter which create area I use, it gets rendered after all the previous ones.

Here's my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [notes2, setNotes2] = useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }
  function addNote2(newNote) {
    setNotes2(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }
  function deleteNote2(id) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote2} />
      {notes.map((noteItem, index1) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index1}
            id={index1}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
      {notes2.map((noteItem, index2) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index2}
            id={index2}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote2}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can test the app by copying the above code instead of App.jsx at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keeper-part-3-completed-forked-idt6m4).

I need to do something like that:

```
-item1
   =nested item 1
   =nested item 2
   =nested item 3
-item 2
```

so I need the second create area to eventually be used for nested items (children). and the 1st create area to be for 'item1' or 'item2' or ... (parent). But with the way it functions from my code, it gets rendered like that:

```
-item1 
-item2
=nested item 1
=nested item 2 
=nested item 3
```

Comment: I'm confused. 1) Why is your input box shown twice above but once at CodeSandbox? 2) What does "kind of the last element of an array" mean? 3) What are "new first" and "new second"? 4) Why do you have pairs of identical add and delete functions? 5) What's the difference between `state.notes` and `state.notes2`?

Comment: 1) please copy the code I shared and paste it inside the link I shared.
2) What I mean is that the reason each new element added is like picture 3 is that it is added to its array (2 arrays are being used) so I want it to "ignore" that fact and render things as if they are a list of items
3) new1st is the new component I added using the above section. new2nd is the new component I added using the below section.
4) they are not identical. each for each create area.

Comment: 5) different Arrays for 2 different components. 
and sorry for the hastle, you can copy the whole code and replace it with App.jsx

Comment: FYI, your form should have `max-width: 100%` to prevent Y-overflow, and your footer should have `width: calc(100% - 32px)` to account for the body padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand a reason why you would want to do that. You need to either have **one** list or **two**. If for rendering, you want it to be one list, you can have that in a single state. Also if it's just about having two input fields to add note, both fields can push to same state. Here is how it could be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((noteItem, index1) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index1}
            id={index1}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Well, if you still want it :D  then here is a thing you can do:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [notes2, setNotes2] = useState([]);

  const [combinedNotes, setCombinedNotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const notesList = [...notes, ...notes2].sort((note1, note2) => note1.timestamp - note2.timestamp);
    setCombinedNotes(notesList);
  }, [notes, notes2]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, { ...newNote, timestamp: new Date().getTime() }];
    });
  }

  function addNote2(newNote) {
    setNotes2(prevNotes => {
      return [...prevNotes, { ...newNote, timestamp: new Date().getTime() }];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    const isFirstNote = notes.find((note) => note.timestamp === id);
    if (isFirstNote) {
      setNotes(prevNotes => {
        return prevNotes.filter((noteItem) => {
          return noteItem.timestamp !== id;
        });
      });
    } else {
      setNotes2(prevNotes => {
        return prevNotes.filter((noteItem) => {
          return noteItem.timestamp !== id;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote2} />
      {combinedNotes((noteItem, index) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={noteItem.timestamp}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I understand that but I need to do something like that:
-item1
      =nested item 1
      =nested item 2
      =nested item 3
-item 2

so I need the second create area to eventually be used for nested items (children). and the 1st create area to be for 'item1' or 'item2' or ... (parent). But with the way it functions from my code, it gets rendered like that:

-item1
-item 2
      =nested item 1
      =nested item 2
      =nested item 3

Comment: I have edited the question (added this comment with proper stucture) to elaborate more on what I mean.

Comment: check now. if I understood correctly. for any modifications, you can play around.

Comment: I get an error " cannot access "notes" before initialization " `const notes = [...notes,...notes2]`. Much Appreciated.

Comment: There was an error with variable name.  Updated.